# Increase NavigationBar height

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have the following code:

```
func navbarbutton() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
        let current = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame!.origin.x, self.frame!.origin.y, self.frame!.size.width, current!.size.height + 50)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

I'm able to increase the height of the navigation bar by 50 dp. That's not the issue for me. The issue I'm having is that the `UIBarButtonItems` are all aligned to the bottom. How can I get them aligned to the top so that I can add more to the bottom myself? I'm getting something as per the image:

[image]

Is it possible to get it aligned to the top?

Comment: check my answer and let me know the code works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

**Note:** Code tested in Swift 3.

**Answer 1:** **Updated Answer**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var customBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Title
    title = "Some Title"

    // Add bar button item
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action:  #selector(addTapped))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))

    self.customBar.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.frame.width, height:(navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + 50)  
    self.customBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    self.view.addSubview(customBar)
}

func addTapped() {

    print("Button Pressed")

}
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Answer 2:**

```
override var isViewLoaded: Bool {

    // Add bar button item
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action:  #selector(addTapped))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))

    //Vertical and Horizonal barButtonItem position offset
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 20), for: UIBarMetrics.default)

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 20), for: UIBarMetrics.default)

    return true
}

func addTapped() {

    print("Button Pressed")

}
```

**Note:** Above code only works in **isViewLoaded: Bool** method.But, No luck.When, I tried this code in other viewLoad method.

**Output 1:** barButtonItem moved 20 pixel up vertically.

[image]

**Output 2:** barButtonItem moved 20 pixel down vertically.

[image]

Hope, Above code fix your problem.

Comment: one more question, how does Apple make it so that it animates so nicely when the user presses the back button? When going to the page it increases and decreases when going back!

Comment: You could try something like this.....func backTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}   .....untested code .so, let me know

Comment: any luck?. I just created a simple animation on back button while VC transition...let me know. i will update the answer...

Comment: I have animation but i'm looking for something like Apple's Messages. As you slide across with your finger to see the previous screen the nav bar slowly updates. Its also on googles hangouts app.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't do that.

The view hierarchy within the `UINavigationBar` is private so you can't manipulate it without iterating over the subviews and going all hacky with it. This probably isn't a good idea.

Out of curiosity I looked at the Messages app in iOS 10 using the view debugger because they obviously do this. They actually achieve the layout by adding their own `UIButton` to replace the back and rightBarButtonItem. This is something you would be able to do however they also set the alpha of one of the internal (and private) content views to zero so that the original content is no longer visible.
This is something that you won't be able to do so easily unfortunately. You could try to hack things about until it works but remember you also need to handle pushes/pops, in call status bars, interactive transitions and rotation events.

If however you wasn't going for the iMessage style and just wanted to add some content underneath your navigation bar, why not look at pinning a `UIVisualEffectView` to the `topLayoutGuide` in your `UIViewController`? You can get a fairly nice look pretty easily and it saves hacking stuff about a lot. Here's an example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Do you know how Google did it in the Hangouts app?

Comment: @KVISH: I suspect they have some sort of custom navigation controller judging by how much it differs to the standard `UINavigationController` but I don't know for sure