# how to adjust y-axis of back button in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have created a custom navigation controller subclassing `UINavigationController`. now when i increase the size of navigation bar then the back button also slides down. `Then how to adjust the y-axis of back button.`

[image]

```
self.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 64.0)
```

I am able to adjust the y axis of title by below code

```
self.navigationBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(-30, for: .default)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate. check my answer...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316352/increase-navigationbar-height/40320225#40320225

Comment: @Joe - i am looking for a solution that will work with code written in subclass of UINavigationController. not in UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

Try
- (void)setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:(UIOffset)adjustment 
                               forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics;
- (void)setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:(CGFloat)adjustment 
                                            forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics;

Comment: Although C answers are excepted on swift tagged posts you might help the OP more with a pure swift post, formatting the post will also help increase the readability

Answer (score 0):

This works in **Swift 3**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 100)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.yellow
    self.title = "My Title"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(-30, for: .default)
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "myButton", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(myViewController.myFunc))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitlePositionAdjustment(.init(horizontal: 0, vertical: -30), for: .default)
```

[image]

Comment: this is not working when i am using your code in the subclass of UINavigationController