# How can I change height of Navigation Bar - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm pretty sure this is not duplicate because I looked at other answers and they all outdated and do not provide exact answer.

I have Navigation Controller and several view controllers. I want to make Navigation Bar a bit taller so it would fit text size that I need. How can I do that ?

I tried this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 320.0, height: 210.0)
```

but nothing happens...

Also, I wasn't able to add any constraints to the Nav Bar using Xcode layout buttons.

Hope somebody can help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316352/increase-navigationbar-height/40320225#40320225

Comment: > If you are trying to do something else that requires the navigation bar to be resized, that's not supported. openradar.appspot.com/32912789

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**UPDATE 8/3/20: I posted this in 2016.  A number of people have stated this no longer works so please use at your own risk.  I am not working in iOS at the moment so I do not have an update handy.  Best of luck!**

Here is one way to do it:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let height: CGFloat = 50 //whatever height you want to add to the existing height
    let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)
    
}
```

Comment: Great thanks for your answer, worked just fine. To my surprise I added that code in one VC and it worked for the entire app... I tried to change your code a bit and enter it to App Delegate but it didn't work unfortunately. But I guess that's fine.

Comment: @KirillC You could subclass UINavigationController and add Frankie's code there.

Comment: @KirillC You're welcome.  Please consider accepting the answer if it helped.  You could do as Brett said.  Also if you only need it to work in one VC you could add a similar method to viewWillDisappear to change the height back.

Comment: I just added the code to my initial VC and it works fine on all other VCs, why should I subclass?

Comment: I think he was suggesting that you 'could' subclass, not necessarily 'should' subclass.  Depends on your situation.  Your initial VC probably has the same navigation controller as your other vc's, therefore it suffices.  If you had multiple navigation controllers throughout your app, it would make sense to subclass as opposed to rewriting the same code in each one.  If my answer helped you I'd appreciate if you accepted the answer, thanks!

Comment: Subclassing doesn't work with the above code, I'm getting an error `unexpected found nil`. See picture: http://imgur.com/a/Oyuy3

Comment: @MarksCode If you’re in a `UINavigationController` subclass probably need to change any references of `self.navigationController` to just `self`.

Comment: @Frankie this works for me.. but I am facing another issue here. If I click device home button and open the app again, the navigation bar jumps to top and there is a gap between my view nd navigationbar. Any idea? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @QUserS I'm not certain if it's related or not.  I'd recommend posting another question with detailed code, images, etc, and see if someone can help you.

Comment: I tried it and it simply does not work. Maybe it's the new iOS version, but there's no effect after calling this code.

Comment: > If you are trying to do something else that requires the navigation bar to be resized, that's not supported. https://openradar.appspot.com/32912789

Answer (score 12):

You can write this code in class that extends UINavigationController

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let height = CGFloat(72)
    navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: height)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can create a class based on `UINavigationBar` like this

```
class TTNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 55)
    }

}
```

And add it to your NavigationController.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this method never gets called in my case? I basically just copy-pasted this code to my custom UINavigationBar class and set it in storyboard on my navigation bars.

Comment: @andrejbroncek are you sure your custom UINavigationBar it's executing?
-One common problem is that sometimes you end up with several UINavigationController and maybe your custom UINavigationBar is never executed or is not the one that is displayed

Comment: same problem, does not get executed

Comment: for some reasons iOS 13 doesn't call this method

Answer (score 4):

This might be better if your navigation bars in your app all have same adjusted height.

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    open override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 51)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you can draw your navigation bar from xib (with your height) and then:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(yourNavBarView)
```

in alternative, if you want create UIView from code,

```
let viewNavBar = UIView(frame: CGRect(
    origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y:0), 
    size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 100)))
```

and then adding to nav bar.

Comment: You do not need to say `init` like that. — A major flaw here is that you have created a vanilla UIView, not a UINavigationBar which is what the OP wants.