# can't change the height for the navigation bar in swift 4

Tags: swift4

i hope all is well

please i have an issue for i try change the height navigation bar it's not change it please how can i change it i use the code below but it's not working:

```
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 3.0) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100)
```

}

please how can i change the height for the navigation bar

thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change height of Navigation Bar Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751366/how-can-i-change-height-of-navigation-bar-swift-3)

Comment: My Friend i try to implement theses answers that you flag it to me but it’s not solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i know you cant change the height for the navigation bar but you can use something called LargeTitle using this

```
 navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

this will expand the height of the navigation bar try it might solve your problem

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7caxpp3Xps check out this video 
this could help you also

Comment: it's expand it but i can not add to the bottom navigation bar another view