# Change height of navigation bar ios

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the height of the navigation bar with this code provided in few links over stackoverflow, but it is not working as required.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.frame.origin.y, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 200)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Is there anything additional that I need to add to make it work ?

I did checked the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751366/how-can-i-change-height-of-navigation-bar-swift-3) link too but it is not working, also it is the same as I written with added fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change height of Navigation Bar Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751366/how-can-i-change-height-of-navigation-bar-swift-3)

Comment: I did checked the referenced link too but it is not working, also it is the same as I written with added fix.

Comment: No there is no error message; it just dont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hierarchy of UINavigationBar view is private so we can't manipulate it.We create our custom view and add into a Viewcontroller.