# How can i remove this black line from custom navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

Here what i done for custom navigation controller.i was added this code inside of viewDidLoad method.

```
    import UIKit

class Login: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigatonBar()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func navigatonBar(){

        let codedLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
        codedLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:-45, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)
        codedLabel.textAlignment = .center
        codedLabel.text = "Login"
        codedLabel.textColor = .white
        codedLabel.font=UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
        let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width,height: 75))

        navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
        self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
        self.view.addSubview(codedLabel)



    }


}
```

[image]

but i am getting a Black line in the navigation

Comment: can you please provide more context

Comment: yes.. i added more line

Comment: So you have a custom UINavigationController and add a second UINavigationBar as a subview? Please provide all of the navigation controller code.

Comment: There is no other code in my view controller

Comment: Might be a good idea to post a screenshot from your simulator to see what you're referencing.

Comment: Just added  screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to determine the exact issue since you haven't posted all of your code, but my guess is that you have a `UINavigationController` with a custom view controller as the root view controller of the `UINavigationController`. If this is the case, I believe your issue is that you're adding a second navigation bar as a subview of your custom view controller's view.  Don't do that. Remove the code below:

```
let codedLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
codedLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:-45, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)
codedLabel.textAlignment = .center
codedLabel.text = "Login"
codedLabel.textColor = .white
codedLabel.font=UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width,height: 75))

navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
self.view.addSubview(codedLabel)
```

and customize the `UINavigationController`'s `UINavigationBar`:

```
self.title = "Login"
if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
    navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
    navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font:  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
}
```

Comment: i was added all code. but i need a custom navigation bar which has more hight than default navigation bar

Comment: Then you need to post a new question about a navigation bar with custom height :)

Comment: Do you have any reference ? about custom navigation bar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751366/how-can-i-change-height-of-navigation-bar-swift-3

Comment: can you please add the title font attribute

Comment: Title color is not changing

Comment: updated the titleTextAttributes to include `NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white`, try it now

Answer (score 0):

im pretty sure that is the shadowImage, to remove it just add this `navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()`, doesn't work if you set it to nil (nil is the default value). Edit: I missed the translucent point, set translucent to false, if don't the nav bar will add a UIVisualEffect on the navBar code : `navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`