# How to change navigation bar height in iOS 12.2?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

This is my design to create custom navigation bar.

[image: I am trying this output.]

I am hardly trying to change navigation bar height. I have tried many links from Stack Overflow but can not figure it out. this is reference image i want to make a same navigation bar. i don't want to use UIView.

Facing issue - Can not change height of navigation bar.

i am using this code.

```
// First
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 80.0)

// Second
for subview in (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
       if NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder).contains("BarBackground") {
            var subViewFrame: CGRect = subview.frame
            // subViewFrame.origin.y = -20;
            subViewFrame.size.height = 100
            subview.frame = subViewFrame

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default navigation bar property form Storyboard.
[Reference for more.](https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/large-titles-ios-11/)
[image: Set as per application theme.]

You can also change programatically. In some of the screens Larger navigation is not required then you can set from controller class also.

Comment: my requirement is i want to set 87 navigation bar height.

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751366/how-can-i-change-height-of-navigation-bar-swift-3/45401474#45401474

Comment: I did but it's not working as well. i have spent a day on this task.