# How to change the height of the naviagtionBar

Tags: swift

In the latest version of xcode, I wrote the following code in the viewDidLoad to change the height of the NavigationBar.

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height:40)`

However, I couldn't change the height of the NavigationBar.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change height of Navigation Bar - Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751366/how-can-i-change-height-of-navigation-bar-swift-3)

Comment: please let me know if my answer solved your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly 2 Approaches that i used

**First Approach**

Better to create Subclass of `UINavigationController` ... and add this method there .. Use this class as `NavigationController`

```
  class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
           super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
           let height = CGFloat(72)
           navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: height)
       }

}
```

**Second workaround**

You can create a Subclass of `UINavigationBar` like this

```
class MyNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 75)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you!! The First Approach was able to build successfully. However, the second approach didn't work.