# Reducing the height of the Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, frontend, uinavigationbar

What is the method for reducing the height of the Navigation Bar? This question was posed in a slightly different way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751366/how-can-i-change-height-of-navigation-bar-swift-3?noredirect=1&lq=1) 4 years ago, but the proposed answer doesn't seem to work anymore, at least for me. Is there an updated method that anyone is aware of? Many thanks.

Comment: Does this work for you? `navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false`?

Comment: That is not working for me.

Comment: I'd recommend hiding the navigation bar and using a plain UIView instead.

Comment: Hide the actual navigation bar and show your own pseudo-navigation bar?