# Make buttons behind NavBar clickable

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

So I'm working on a project where we are doing a custom header which collapses/expands as the user drags either the header or a scrollview/tableview.
In some cases we want to have buttons in the header that will end up where the navbar is in a collapsed state, which gets animated in a nice way to there.

So the problem is when the button gets behind the navbar (a transparent one) its not clickable anymore.
We tried altering the Z layer for the button and the "bringSubviewToFront" but none works.
We also tried to alter the height of the navbar [according to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751366/how-can-i-change-height-of-navigation-bar-swift-3/40751518#40751518) but it seems as well its not working anymore. Also, just hiding the navbar would not be a passable solution as we sometimes will need the back button there as well.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tANgo.png)

So if anyone have any good answer or workaround for this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

We are using the answer in the appDelegate from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845855/transparent-navigation-bar-ios) to make the navbar transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using Hit Test, it should be able to do what you need:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest