# center navigation bar views vertically

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I managed to increase the height of my navigation bar, but I faced with the problem, that title and buttons are situated in the bottom of navigator bar.

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    open override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let v = self.value(forKey: "frame") as? CGRect
        return v?.size ?? CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44)
    }

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 64)
}
```

[image]

I tried to set offset, using

```
navigationBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(-10, for: .default)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(-10, for: .default)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(-10, for: .default)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(-10, for: .default)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(-10, for: .default)
```

Actually that setting only apply to my title, and the position of button bars remain the same.

But I don't think my solution is the best.

Comment: why don't you show how exactly did you increase the navigation bar height?

Comment: Couple links in the comments on this question may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181264/move-navigationbars-left-and-right-barbuttonitems-vertically-upwards

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good practice to increase the size of the navigation bar. Instead you can add a uiview right under navigation bar with same color and remove the navigation bar border to make to look like height increased. Here is an example how yelp does it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I posted the solution of this problem in another thread. Hope this helps.

[vertically aligning UINavigationItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566216/vertically-aligning-uinavigationitems/46170241#46170241)